# Why do I get an error "package org.mockito.runners does not exist"?

Tags: java, android, testing, mocking, mockito

I have pluged up require dependency

```
testCompile 'org.mockito:mockito-core:1.10.19'
```

Then I put my test code to `/src/test/java/` directory

then I have tried launch such test

```
import org.junit.Test;
import static org.hamcrest.CoreMatchers.is;
import static org.hamcrest.MatcherAssert.assertThat;

public class PresenterActivityAcceptNotAcceptTest {

@Test
public void emailValidator_CorrectEmailSimple_ReturnsTrue() {
    boolean dd = true;
    assertThat(dd, is(true));
}
```

it works properly, but if I add anything witch associated with `Mock` lib

for example `@RunWith`

```
    import org.junit.Test;
    import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
    import org.mockito.runners.MockitoJUnitRunner;

    import static org.hamcrest.CoreMatchers.is;
    import static org.hamcrest.MatcherAssert.assertThat;

@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class PresenterActivityAcceptNotAcceptTest {


    @Test
    public void emailValidator_CorrectEmailSimple_ReturnsTrue() {
        boolean dd = true;
        assertThat(dd, is(true));
    }
```

I got such error

```
Error:Execution failed for task   ':Application:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.
Error:(10, 10) error: cannot find symbol class MockitoJUnitRunner
Error:(5, 27) error: package org.mockito.runners does not exist
/home/aleksey/Downloads/NTZ/FittingRoom/Application/src/test/java/com/fittingroom/newtimezone/presenters/PresenterActivityAcceptNotAcceptTest.java
```

What am I doing wrong?

If I forger about something feel free to ask

Thanks in advance!

Comment: check require dependency and its scope

Comment: is your test comlipable? did you already trying to clean the project?

Comment: @PSM what do you mean? as I mentioned in question I have already added this dependency...

Comment: @TimothyTruckle no... I got this error during compilation... What does it mean?

Comment: Try replacing testCompile with androidTestCompile

Comment: androidTestCompile "org.mockito:mockito-core:1.10.19"

Comment: @PSM no with this way androidStudio even can't recognize this import `import org.mockito.runners.MockitoJUnitRunner;`

Comment: It looks like Gradle is not doing it's job.

Manually adding the jars fixed the problem.

Comment: @PSM Yes! You are right! Thanks a lot! If you publish answer I will approve it

Comment: approve my answer

Comment: @AlekseyTimoshchenko is it a multi project configuration?

Comment: @TimothyTruckle what does it mean multi project configuration?

Comment: @AlekseyTimoshchenko *"what does it mean multi project configuration"* If you have to ask you probably don't have it... ;o) https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/multi_project_builds.html

Comment: I think Instant Run has some guilt on this.

Comment: @Chisko what do you mean?

Comment: @AlekseyTimoshchenko did you add the dependency later in the project? did you run "gradle->update project" after adding mockito?

Comment: @TimothyTruckle sorry, but where this button `gradle->update project` placed?

Comment: @AlekseyTimoshchenko *"where this button"* its in the context menu of the project.

Comment: @TimothyTruckle unfurtunately I don't have such button( I have looked through all studio components and eventually have not found any ....

Comment: @AlekseyTimoshchenko: OK, one step back: do you get the error at the command line or in your IDE?

Comment: @TimothyTruckle eventually I have alredy solved this issue, but I am very wondering with your point of view... I got error during compilition process in IDE

Comment: it's incredible!! After 4 years this is still an issue!!!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It looks like Gradle is not doing it's job.
Manually adding the jars may fixed the problem.
[How to Download and Install jar go here .](https://github.com/junit-team/junit4/wiki/Download-and-Install)

and for download mockito use this link

https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.mockito/mockito-core/1.10.19

Answer (score 11):

As stated in [Baeldung's article](https://www.baeldung.com/mockito-deprecated-mockitojunitrunner), starting from Mockito version `2.2.20`, the package for `MockitoJUnitRunner` has changed. So change :

```java
import org.mockito.runners.MockitoJUnitRunner;
```

To :

```
import org.mockito.junit.MockitoJUnitRunner;
```

As usual, you have to import the `mockito-core` library in your `build.gradle` :

```
dependencies {
    testImplementation 'org.mockito:mockito-core:4.2.0'
}
```

As a side note, you will also need to change import for `Matchers` if you use them. For instance :

From :

```
import static org.mockito.Matchers.any;
```

To :

```
import static org.mockito.Mockito.any;
```

Comment: This is the correct answer IMO. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Got the same issue. Attempted to implement the developer.android documentation example.

Fixed by changed org.mockito version to the recent at the time in build.gradle :

```
dependencies {
    testImplementation 'org.mockito:mockito-core:2.28.2'
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Open **File** > **Project Structure...**

and then add it manually as *library dependency*:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I also got this exception when I tried to write `instrumentalTests` in `src/androidTest/java/` but by default mockito's scope in dependencies is set as **Unit Test implementation** (you can see that in `File` => `Project Structure` => `Modules` => `Dependencies`). I've just changed this parameter to **Test implementation** and it works!

[image]

Answer (score -1):

does your project look like this?:
[image]

Comment: It looks like you use eclipse... I use AndroidStudio

Comment: @AlekseyTimoshchenko Yes, I use eclipse. But AS might also have "gradle personality" (or what ever they call it) for projects. As long as you have a "plain Java" Project in AS it will not track your changes to the gradle build file(s).